# Adding my Logo to ms-designer-ribbon instead of global nav-Bar

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am new to SharePoint designing. I want to add my logo to my  ms-designer-ribbon, not my global nav-bar. How can I do this ? Any guidance will really be helpful.

Comment: can you share screenshot of where exactly you need to place in ribbon ?

Comment: By "Logo" do you mean the icons for options that appear in the ribbon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys.. i was able to add my logo by adding the image via content:before property in css for the id "suiteBarLeft" in the PublishingRibbon. I did not change the SharePoint code that calls the ribbon.ascx. i just added my logo by applying CSS to a id in the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: You can't.

Long Answer: Remove the ribbon from the masterpage and re-build your own ribbon, including your logo. Make sure that you do not forget any of the default elements that make the ribbon.
[This post](http://ericoverfield.com/modify-sharepoint-2013-ribbon-help-ribbon-ascx/) shows how it is done. However, I would highly recomend **not** doing it.

An alternative (different, not better...) would be to add a custom ribbon action and in that, using javascript, modify the existing ribbon. I'm not entirely sure this could work, though.